# Schema for MS BizTalk ESB Toolkit 2.0 Fault Message

Tags: xsd, biztalk, esb, biztalk-2009, esb-toolkit-2.0

Does anyone know where I can find a copy of the XSD for the BizTalk ESB Toolkit's fault message?  I have a sample XML file which I could use to generate such a schema, but if there are any unpopulated nillable elements or type restrictions those wouldn't be available from a generated schema.  I've tried to track down a copy of the XSD but so far haven't had any luck.

The namespace and root element from the sample file are included below:

```
<ns0:FaultMessage xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.biztalk.practices.esb.com/exceptionhandling">
    <!-- ... -->
</ns0:FaultMessage>
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The schema is installed in Biztalk application Microsoft.Practices.ESB. To view the schema, go to Biztalk Admin Console. Choose Microsoft.Practices.ESB application and Choose the 'Schemas'. You will see the fault schema listed there. To see the schema , double click on it. The screenshot below shows the schema in question.[image: Biztalk ESB fault message schema viewing]